# Model infos not showing up on HTML page Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am trying to create an educational website using Django, so when I am trying to render {{ profile.institution }} or {{ profile.grade }} or {{ profile.user.username }} they are not being rendered.I don't know why they aren't. Can anyone help me solve this?

My models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    institution = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices= YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

My views.py:

```
class User_Profile(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'class/profile.html'
    context_object_name = 'profile'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Profile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

My html:

```
{% extends "class/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <br>
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        <h1 style="color: #f5a425">Hello {{ user.username }}</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container mt-5">
        
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            
            <div class="col-md-7">
                
                <div class="card p-3 py-4">
                    
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <i class='fas fa-user-alt' style='font-size:36px'></i>
                        <!-- <img src="" width="100" class="rounded-circle"> -->
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="text-center mt-3">
                        <span class="bg-secondary p-1 px-4 rounded text-white">Pro</span>
                        <h5 class="mt-2 mb-0">{{ profile.user.username }}</h5>
                        <span>{{ profile.institution }}</span>
                        <span>{{ profile.grade }} Grade</span>

                        
                        <div class="px-4 mt-1">
                            <p class="fonts">{{ profile.bio }}</p>
                        
                        </div>

                        
                        <div class="buttons">
                            
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary px-4">Message</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary px-4 ms-3">Contact</button>
                        </div>
                        
                        
                    </div>
                    
                   
                    
                    
                </div>
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Are you iterating over object_list?

Comment: no bro I am not iterating

Comment: what part of the code should I change to make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what part of the code should I change to make this work ?

`ListView` it is about many objects ant iteration through the `object_list`. In this case the answer of @PouyaEsmaeili is correct.

But. The mistake is - you have a wrong view. DetailView is the right choose.
This returns always one object or nothing.

```
Profile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

In your case:

```
class User_Profile(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'class/profile.html'
    context_object_name = 'profile'

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(self.model, user=self.request.user)
```

If you set name for template `profile_detail.html`, you don't need `template_name` attribute. It should be find automatically.
If you don't change the `model_name` in Profile._meta - , you don't need `context_object_name` attribute. It should be defined automatically.
Please, don't forget about Django-views naming best practices.

Last version of your view can be:

```
class ProfileDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Profile

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(self.model, user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: says `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'get_object_or_404'`

Comment: i update the answer. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404